# Make a USB drive bootable for Windows 7 setup

Tags: windows, hard-disk, usb-drive, boot-loader

What is the equivalent of [`bootsect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff794683%28v=winembedded.60%29.aspx) command available in Windows, on a *nix system?

**Usage:**

In order to make a USB drive bootable for Windows 7 setup I have to boot-up VMWare and run `bootsect.exe /nt60 e: /force` (`e:` being the USB drive). So was wondering if I could perform that particular operation natively.

Comment: What are you using bootsect for? This is a very OS-dependent area, the functionality is not broken down in the same way.

Comment: I would suggest you to look at `grub` or `grub2` or other bootloaders, but that's not really equivalent of bootsect

Comment: @Gilles question updated.